# Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls giving warnings when updated project to Fall Creators Update - Visual Studio UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, controls, nuget

I needed to change the min version as I must implement SQL framework.

Unfortunately, after changing min version to Fall Creators Update I get multiple reference errors, all talking about dll's missing like this:

> The referenced component '(...)Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\netstandard.library\2.0.2\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Drawing.dll' could not be found

I get 116 warnings in total. I can still build and launch app, however it makes me wonder whats wrong.

I am pretty much sure whats giving these warnings.
I recreated the app by creating new solution and project and moving all code from the previous version.

Everything went smooth until I installed this:

> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls

And the warnings appeared again.

The app works anyway, and the controls from the package I use work well too. 
But whats wrong with the package? Is it not compatible with fall creators update?

Is there a mode to fix it? Or can I ignore it?

Comment: I have the same problem in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls giving warnings when updated project to Fall Creators Update - Visual Studio UWP

This issue should be an issue about the package `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls`.

According to the error message:

> The referenced component '(...)Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\netstandard.library\2.0.2\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Drawing.dll'
>   could not be found

It seems **the UWP project missing the .net standard 2.0 references after installing the package** `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls`. So, to resolve this issue, we could add the .net standard library 2.0 package to the UWP project.

Besides, when I wanted to report this issue to the author of the package, I discovered that you have already done that. This is great. And I have found devsko provided the workaround, I post it here, so this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread:

> I just added Netstandard.Library package with NuGet Package Manager to my UWP library. That solved my problem

Certified: [The referenced component could not be found - warnings in Fall Creators Update Min Target](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2087).